# Harddrive still available after being unplugged. How is this possible?

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, umount

I have an external USB harddrive at

```
/media/hakon/0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9/
```

Now I unplugged it, and I can still type things like

```
ls /media/hakon/0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9/
```

and it shows me the content of the harddrive. Is this some kind of buffering I am not aware of?

If I type

```
sudo umount /media/hakon/0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9/
```

I get the following output:

```
umount: /media/hakon/0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9/: not mounted
```

If I open one of the files on the drive in `vim` and modify it and then save, I works fine (!). Provided I run `vim` with `sudo`. If I later reopen the file, the change I made is still there.. I think this is very strange.

**Update**:

If I run

```
df /media/hakon/0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9/
```

I get output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      945076612 143463104 753583300  16% /
```

Where `/dev/sda1` is the internal 1TB harddrive on my laptop. So it seems to me that the whole content of the USB harddrive has been copied to my internal harddrive somehow. How is this possible?

Comment: It looks like you have actually put files in /media/hakon/0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9/, which is now just a directory on your hard disk and not the external disk, as the disk is not mounted.  Reboot without the external drive connected, and you should still see the files.